# Bootable USB HD

Tags: uefi, usb-storage

I have an USB external hard disk with windows DVD files AND my personal files

To boot on this HD, all I had to do was change UEFI to Legacy on the BIOS

Now, I don't have this option.
Also, don't have and don't want to have an USB stick laying around.

How can I make this USB HDD readable by UEFI, without losing my stuff or the ability to have windows plus stuff side by side ?

Thank you ahead

Comment: You can't due to Windows strict requirements. Windows only installs in Legacy mode to MBR drives and in UEFI mode to GPT drives.

Comment: Are you sure ? In Rufus, there's an option to use MBR AND UEFI/Legacy mix  :/

Comment: You should be able to install a legacy version of `grub` and then boot off the MBR of your windows drive. I would recommend getting a completely separate USB drive and install legacy grub on there. Also, as a point of caution, I would physically unplug all my other drives (even internal drive) when you do this so you don't mess anything up. <- I do this same process when installing Windows because Windows in dumb and doesn't give you the option to specify which GPT to install to, if it finds one, it installs to it, but I like to have multiple on my machines, so, must physically unplug them.

Comment: Thank you. It's an effective workaround. But since I don't have the multiple OS problem, carrying a thumb drive with UEFI seems easier.  :D

Comment: What if I make another partition on the HD ? Would it work or waste my time ? What format should I make it ? Can I mix GPT and MBR on the same device ? Would Rufus recognize it ?